# Почему выдает ошибку при запросе Cursor'а?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

создал БД, вывожу данные в ListView, экспериментирую, решил вывести отсортированные данные по убыванию/возрастанию(не столь важно).
Собственно, при такой записи:

```
    public  Cursor getAllDate()
{
    return refillDB.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, COLUMN_COINS);
}
```

все данные правильно сортируются по возрастанию, однако в учебнике где я это нашел написано: 
[image: Д.Гриффитс. Head First. Программирование для Android.]

делая запрос в соответствии с учебником:

```
    public  Cursor getAllDate()
{
    return refillDB.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, "COLUMN_COINS ASC");
}
```

выдает ошибку 
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: COLUMN_COINS.

Уже всю голову сломал ведь другие методы сортировки не работают, только стандартный "по возрастанию".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оно ж черным по белому пишет, что не может найти столбец `COLUMN_COINS` в таблице. скорее всего ваша константа COLUMN_COINS имеет другое значение. так что напишите не `"COLUMN_COINS ASC"` а `COLUMN_COINS + " ASC"`

Comment: спасибо, все работает. Я все никак не мог понять правильное написание запроса, ведь в учебнике то пунктуация другая =_=