# как правильно запросить максимальное значение в столбце?

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

имеется таблица со столбцами, хочу выцепить из столбца максимальное значение, но что то делаю не правильно. Пробовал разные варианты

вар. 1

```
    public Cursor getMaxY()
{
    return refillDB.query(DB_TABLE,
            new String[] {"MAX(COLUMN_COINS)"},
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

вар. 2

```
    public Cursor getMaxY()
{
    return refillDB.query(DB_TABLE,
            new String[] {"select max(COLUMN_COINS)"},
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

но они не работают.

вот так запрашиваю курсор

```
        cursorMaxY = db.getMaxY();
    startManagingCursor(cursorMaxY);
    maxy = cursorMaxY.getDouble(0);
```

Comment: Вы ставили Cursor в cursor.moveToFirst();? Приложите к вопросу то как вы обрабатываете Cursor.

Comment: Было бы неплохо закинуть в вопрос схему данных таблицы и больше инфы о получаемым ошибкам. 
На глаз кажется, что db.query используются неправильно. Вторым параметром этого метода должен идти список столбцов таблицы. 
См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729011/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-cursor%D0%B0

Comment: @dred так вторым  параметром как раз и идет список столбцов к которому применяется выборка столбца с максимальным значением

Comment: {"MAX(COLUMN_COINS)"} - не похож на писок, список может выглядить так, например: {"id", "name"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все заработало используя вот такое написание:

```
    public Cursor getMaxY()
{
    return refillDB.query(DB_TABLE,
            new String[] {"MAX(" + COLUMN_COINS + ")"},
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```